# Передать $_SESSION с домена на субдомен

Tags: сессия, домен, поддомены, captcha

Такая проблема. Имеется `catalog.satyjy.biz/index.php` - на этой страницы подгружается `captcha.php` рисунок с каптчей которая располагается `satyjy.biz/php/captcha.php`,   в ней  прописано:

```
session_start();
$Random = rand(10001, 99999);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $Random;
........и т.д.
```

то есть каждый раз выдается рандомная каптча и записывается в сессию `$_SESSION['captcha']` на главной странице `satyjy.biz;`

Но при обращении к `$_SESSION['captcha']` - на странице `catalog.satyjy.biz/index.php` - сессия пуста, я так понял сессия не передается с домена на поддомен.

Как сделать перенос сессии с домена на поддомены?

Comment: session_set_cookie_params() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Параметр domain

> domain >
>   Домен, которому доступны cookie. Задание домена 'www.example.com' сделает cookie доступными в поддомене www и поддоменах более высоких порядков. Cookie доступные низким уровням, таким как 'example.com', будут доступны во всех поддоменах высших уровней, с том числе 'www.example.com'. Старые броузеры, следующие устаревшим нормативам » RFC 2109, могут требовать . перед доменом, чтобы включались все поддомены.